# Assigning one refcursor to another refcursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a huge sub query which resolves into the IN clause of my main query like below:

```
DELETE from my_table where one_column IN (my huge complicated sub query);
```

My sub query is going to return more than one record of only one column of type NUMBER. And is inside a procedure.

For EG:  resultset of my subquery will look like:

```
----------
one_column
----------
23
24
27
34
39
43
48
```

And my main query is going to delete the records based on the values returned by the sub query.

My requirement is: I need to return the output of sub query as a ref cursor. 
What I tried: Executing the query as it is and then after deletion opening a ref cursor and execute the subquery again and returning it. This worked. But I dont want this redundancy.

```
    DELETE from my_table where one_column IN (my huge complicated sub query);
    Open my_cursor for
      my huge complicated  sub query;
```

(This is my_cursor is out variable in the package)

What I want to do:

```
 DECLARE 
        my_cursor_2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        Open my_cursor_2 for
          my huge complicated  sub query;
        my_cursor := my_cursor_2; // something like this - I know this will obviosuly create one more handle for the same resultset and wont serve my purpose. Basically I want to clone the cursor and use it as a different one
        DELETE from my_table where one_column IN (read from my_cursor_2 for input to the delete query);
        And return my_cursor as out var of the procedure
```

Is it possible? OR any other better way to acheive this?

Comment: Does it have to be a `ref cursor`? You could do a `DELETE ... RETURNING`.

Comment: I m not very sure but I dont think so you can use entire result set like you have mentioned using "IN condition". You need to fetch records and use one by one record. I may be wrong, lets see what gurus have to sa

Comment: A ref cursor a PL/SQL reference to an open cursor. As it's not an SQL construct there's no way to refer to it in an SQL statement. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Could what you're doing be accomplished in a single loop? Or is there a reason why you need to return the refcursor that wouldn't work within a loop?

Comment: @hol, I will try using `DELETE... RETURNING INTO` clause. Can I return into a refcursor?